# How to Auto Fill Cells in Excel based on a dependent drop down list?

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets in sheet1 is the master sheet where all data are stored
In sheet2 I want to link the data of sheet1 in sheet2 in different cells

In Sheet1 I have 'Name' 'Mobile' 'Address' 'Pin' in A1 B1 C1 D1

In Sheet2 A2 I did data validation of the name of the persons which is stored in Sheet1, now I want that when I will select the respect list automatically the Mobile Address Pin of the person will auto fill in B2 C2 D2

& for that I am using the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:B,COLUMNS(Sheet1!$A:B),0)
```

If a person having 3 mobile numbers stored in my Sheet1, I want to place those 3 mobile numbers in my Sheet2 Mobile column, How do I do that ??

Column A is the main dependent, But if there are blank rows then Data validation doesn't work, how can I do that ??
or any macro required ??

[image: Check the Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one. You will need to have a unique identifier in your records somewhere because a VLOOK and a MATCH formula will only pull back the first record it finds.

I would suggest looking into this link, it tells you how to do this. I have done it before, but it takes some practice no doubt so be warned.

[Excel to the Next Level by Mastering Multiple Occurrences](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/12/09/multiple-occurrences-lookup-and-extraction/)

Comment: Yes, that link has good information, but it would be great if anyone can do the coding for me

Comment: If you can post your project somewhere I can get to it, I can see about editing it, then posting back with the answer. Can't promise anything, but I got it working with a test sheet this morning.

Comment: can I mail you ? Kindly give me your mail ID